# SwiftUI - List on tvOS - top gradient

Tags: list, swiftui, gradient, tvos

I have a List that I'm implementing in tvOS with swift UI and when scrolling down on the list, a gradient appears at the top of the list (presumably to indicate there are items above)

Essentially, what I'm looking for at the top of the List is:

[image]

But, I'm seeing this:

[image]

How do I remove that top gradient fade and simply have a straight edge?

Answer (score 1):

Use a VStack (or LazyVStack) in a ScrollView. List uses UITableView behind the scenes, which has the fade, but ScrollView does not.